elastic-apm-agent in .net 6 generates a lot of Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntime/ExceptionThrown events
We use prometheus-net.DotNetMetrics for system monitoring in ASP .net6 application. And when we started using Elastic Apm agent for .net, the dotnet_exceptions_total metric began to show increased values for System.NotSupportedException exceptions.

dotnet-trace shows, that the reason is in DataFlow (Task Parallel library). Exceptions have message:

This member is not supported on this dataflow block. The block is
intended for a specific purpose that does not utilize this member.


These exceptions are catched in DataFlow, but create noise in the metric and can affect performance.
Source code, where exception is cached:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/dc0432bcb6e7afba54c426f15d03fe8c8fd0d0aa/src/libraries/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/src/Internal/Common.cs#L384
We have this problem in kubernetes pods, but not in the local machine under the Windows.
Has anyone encountered such a problem?

The reason was in old version of prometheus-net library (v 7.0.0). Upgrading to  version 8 solved my problem.
Details:
I found that the source of the exception is in targetBlock which is of type ReceiveTarget.
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/2831f11ab3adadf867cc96449b36090f4a520f2c/src/libraries/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/src/Base/DataflowBlock.cs#L1390
And the main problem is that the exception occurs when DataflowEtwProvider eventsource is enabled. So it tries to collect tracing data.
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/2831f11ab3adadf867cc96449b36090f4a520f2c/src/libraries/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/src/Internal/TargetRegistry.cs#L100
I think it is not usual behaviour and I need to disabled it. First of all I think that I need to find which EventSource enabled it.
Later I found that listener was in prometheus-net library. In version 7.0.0 it subscribed to all eventsources in app domain.
https://github.com/prometheus-net/prometheus-net/blob/75cc8171a9eb6ceb099b14af70d861cc11c03ccc/Prometheus/EventCounterAdapterOptions.cs#L10
I upgraded it to version 8 and the problem went away.
https://github.com/prometheus-net/prometheus-net/blob/60e9106a83ff1274fec0022c37366f04822b1d1b/Prometheus/EventCounterAdapter.cs#L237
